# In Struts2 how to iterate a list value with if else condition

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am not able to use the if condition in the below code. It displays F and M as per List values but when it comes to condition it just prints "WONG VALUE" irrespective to F or M

```
<s:iterator value="dList" id="dList" status="stat">
    <tr class="<s:if test="#stat.odd == true ">oddrow</s:if><s:else>evenrow</s:else>">
    <td class="td_one1"><div align="center"><s:property value="%{gender}" default ="--" /></div></td>

                             <td class="td_one1">
                             <s:if test="%{gender}=='F'">
                                This is Female
                                </s:if>
                            <s:elseif test="%{gender}=='M'">
                                This is Male
                            </s:elseif>
                            <s:else>
                                WRONG VALUE
                            </s:else>
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                      </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://struts.apache.org/docs/why-wont-the-if-tag-evaluate-a-one-char-string.html.

Comment: Didnt work :(    <s:if test='%{gender}=="M"'>
       This is String 1
       </s:if>
      <s:elseif test='%{gender}=="F"'>
          This is String 2
      </s:elseif>
      <s:else>
          WRONG VALUE
      </s:else>

Comment: Your expression is wrong. Write it like the link shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake - The correct syntax is  `<s:if test='%{gender=="M"}'>` instead of `<s:if test='%{gender}=="M"'>`

Comment: Or just `<s:if test='gender == "M"'>`, because the value of `test` attribute in `<s:if>` tag is already evaluated as OGNL expression.